# Android: How to pass Parcelable object to intent and use getParcelable method of bundle?

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle, parcelable

Why bundle has `getParcelableArrayList`, `getParcelable` methods; but
`Intent` has only `putParcelableArrayListExtra` method?
Can I transmit only `object<T>`, not `ArrayList` of one element?
Then, what is `getParcelable` for?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Intent provides bunch of overloading [putExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable%29) methods.

Suppose you have a class Foo implements Parcelable properly, to put it into Intent in an Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NextActivity.class);
Foo foo = new Foo();
intent.putExtra("foo ", foo);
startActivity(intent);
```

To get it from intent in another activity:

```
Foo foo = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("foo");
```

Comment: I'm getting java.lang.ClassCastException: xxx.CDetails cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable where CDetails is a type of custom model with key and value pairs.                 intent.putExtra("CDetails", (Parcelable) tempCDetails);

Answer (score 1):

```
Parcelable p[] =getIntent().getParcelableArrayExtra("parcel");
```

Comment: i ask about getParcelable , for what it ?

Comment: it will return an array of your object you have passed

Comment: sorry, do you feel the difference between getParcelableArrayExtra and getParcelable ?

Comment: BTW finally what you want to pass ?

Comment: object < T >  , T implements Parcelable, only one object, not array, not list

Comment: this is just a code example you had lying around. He said he had a parcel-able object, not a parcel-able array. Boo!

Answer (score 0):

Sender Activity:

```
val intent = Intent(this, RestaurantDetails::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(Constants.RESTAURANT, restaurant)
        startActivity(intent)
```

Receiver Activity:

```
        val restaurant = intent.getParcelableExtra<Restaurant>(Constants.RESTAURANT)
```

Answer (score -1):

First create Parcelable using [**Given Technique**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-parcelable) then

```
public static CreditCardDetail newInstance(CreditCardItemBO creditCardItem) {
        CreditCardDetail fragment = new CreditCardDetail();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable(CREDIT_KEY,creditCardItem);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

And getting it like

```
 if(getArguments() != null)
 {
    creditCardItem = getArguments().getParcelable(CREDIT_KEY);               
 }
```

> where

```
public static final String CREDIT_KEY = "creditKey";
```

Answer (score -1):

It is important to remember that your models must implement the [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) interface, and the static [CREATOR](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.Creator.html) method. This case is for the lists

```
 private static final String MODEL_LIST = "MODEL_LIST";
    public MainFragment() {}

    public static MainFragment newInstance(ArrayList<YourModel>   
models) {
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelableArrayList(MODEL_LIST,models);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            ArrayList<YourModel> models = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(MODEL_LIST);
        }
    }
```

Comment: OP was asking about why there doesn't exist a putParcelable on Intent, not how to implement Parcelable.