# Pass array of custom objects to another Activity in android

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am new to android programming, and I am trying to send an array of custom objects to a different activity. In the first activity I have a function that creates an intent and adds the array of objects to it:

```
public void openSchedule() {
    Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Schedule.class);
    nextScreen.putExtra("array", tasks);
    startActivity(nextScreen);
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to get that data at the next screen.

Is there any way to get that array in the code for the next activity even though "tasks" is an array of custom objects?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107442/android-how-put-parcelable-object-to-intent-and-use-getparcelable-method-of-bu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't search a lot...

Check this for Parcelable interface : [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

edit : 
This too, https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-Parcelable

Answer (score 6):

Did you try it with [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)?

```
public void openSchedule() {
    Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Schedule.class);
    String arrayAsString = new Gson().toJson(tasks);
    nextScreen.putExtra("array", arrayAsString);
    startActivity(nextScreen);
}
```

In your second activity, parse the extra data back into the `List<T>`

```
public void parseBack(){
    String arrayAsString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("array");
    List<YourType> list = Arrays.asList(new Gson().fromJson(arrayAsString, YourType[].class));
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution.

Comment: Lol, almost forgot abut this one. The sad thing is that I even use Gson in other part of my app to save my object array in shared preferences :/ +1 'cause you reminded me of this

Comment: This worked for me. But I need to store the object in an array list not a regular list. How do I need to edit this piece of code to do so?

Comment: @VaskoVasilev just remove the `Arrays.asList` and you'll get an array.

Comment: It still gives the incompatible types error. The value returned is: 'com.example.pogolemotoproektce.Classes.Book[]'

Comment: @VaskoVasilev do you mind posting a bit more of code?

Answer (score 1):

Have your custom object implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html), in order to make use of [putParcelableArrayListExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E)) from the `Intent` class.