# Pass Object implementing Parcelable from one Activity to Another Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parcelable

**I have reviewed similar questions on SO but I have not achieved the required result**

I'm pulling data from the Movie Database server, I'm parsing that data using Jackson and I'm creating this object on which I need to implement parcelable as in my activity I want to add a list of these objects to the bundle in onSaveInstanceState method.

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Movie implements Parcelable{

@JsonProperty("adult")
private Boolean adult;
@JsonProperty("backdrop_path")
private String backdropPath;
@JsonProperty("genre_ids")
private List<Integer> genreIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
@JsonProperty("id")
private Integer id;
@JsonProperty("original_language")
private String originalLanguage;
@JsonProperty("original_title")
private String originalTitle;
@JsonProperty("overview")
private String overview;
@JsonProperty("release_date")
private String releaseDate;
@JsonProperty("poster_path")
private String posterPath;
@JsonProperty("popularity")
private Double popularity;
@JsonProperty("title")
private String title;
@JsonProperty("video")
private Boolean video;
@JsonProperty("vote_average")
private Double voteAverage;
@JsonProperty("vote_count")
private Integer voteCount;

public Movie(){}

private Movie(Parcel in){

    adult =  (in.readInt() == 0) ? false : true;
    backdropPath = in.readString();
    genreIds = in.readArrayList(List.class.getClassLoader());
    id = in.readInt();
    originalLanguage = in.readString();
    originalTitle = in.readString();
    overview = in.readString();
    releaseDate = in.readString();
    posterPath = in.readString();
    popularity = in.readDouble();
    title = in.readString();
    video = (in.readInt() == 0) ? false : true;
    voteAverage = in.readDouble();
    voteCount = in.readInt();
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The adult
 */
@JsonProperty("adult")
public Boolean getAdult() {return adult;}

/**
 *
 * @param adult
 * The adult
 */
@JsonProperty("adult")
public void setAdult(Boolean adult) {this.adult = adult;}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The backdropPath
 */
@JsonProperty("backdrop_path")
public String getBackdropPath() {return backdropPath;}

/**
 *
 * @param backdropPath
 * The backdrop_path
 */
@JsonProperty("backdrop_path")
public void setBackdropPath(String backdropPath) {this.backdropPath = backdropPath;}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The genreIds
 */
@JsonProperty("genre_ids")
public List<Integer> getGenreIds() {return genreIds;}

/**
 *
 * @param genreIds
 * The genre_ids
 */
@JsonProperty("genre_ids")
public void setGenreIds(List<Integer> genreIds) {this.genreIds = genreIds;}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The id
 */
@JsonProperty("id")
public Integer getId() {return id;}

/**
 *
 * @param id
 * The id
 */
@JsonProperty("id")
public void setId(Integer id) {this.id = id;}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The originalLanguage
 */
@JsonProperty("original_language")
public String getOriginalLanguage() {return originalLanguage;}

/**
 *
 * @param originalLanguage
 * The original_language
 */
@JsonProperty("original_language")
public void setOriginalLanguage(String originalLanguage) {this.originalLanguage = originalLanguage;}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The originalTitle
 */
@JsonProperty("original_title")
public String getOriginalTitle() {return originalTitle;}

/**
 *
 * @param originalTitle
 * The original_title
 */
@JsonProperty("original_title")
public void setOriginalTitle(String originalTitle) {this.originalTitle = originalTitle;}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The overview
 */
@JsonProperty("overview")
public String getOverview() {return overview;}

/**
 *
 * @param overview
 * The overview
 */
@JsonProperty("overview")
public void setOverview(String overview) {this.overview = overview;}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The releaseDate
 */
@JsonProperty("release_date")
public String getReleaseDate() {return releaseDate;}

/**
 *
 * @param releaseDate
 * The release_date
 */
@JsonProperty("release_date")
public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) {this.releaseDate = releaseDate;}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The posterPath
 */
@JsonProperty("poster_path")
public String getPosterPath() {return posterPath;}

/**
 *
 * @param posterPath
 * The poster_path
 */
@JsonProperty("poster_path")
public void setPosterPath(String posterPath) {this.posterPath = posterPath;}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The popularity
 */
@JsonProperty("popularity")
public Double getPopularity() {return popularity;}

/**
 *
 * @param popularity
 * The popularity
 */
@JsonProperty("popularity")
public void setPopularity(Double popularity) {this.popularity = popularity;}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The title
 */
@JsonProperty("title")
public String getTitle() {return title;}

/**
 *
 * @param title
 * The title
 */
@JsonProperty("title")
public void setTitle(String title) {this.title = title;}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The video
 */
@JsonProperty("video")
public Boolean getVideo() {
    return video;
}

/**
 *
 * @param video
 * The video
 */
@JsonProperty("video")
public void setVideo(Boolean video) {this.video = video;}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The voteAverage
 */
@JsonProperty("vote_average")
public Double getVoteAverage() {return voteAverage;}

/**
 *
 * @param voteAverage
 * The vote_average
 */
@JsonProperty("vote_average")
public void setVoteAverage(Double voteAverage) {this.voteAverage = voteAverage;}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The voteCount
 */
@JsonProperty("vote_count")
public Integer getVoteCount() {return voteCount;}

/**
 *
 * @param voteCount
 * The vote_count
 */
@JsonProperty("vote_count")
public void setVoteCount(Integer voteCount) {this.voteCount = voteCount;}


/**
 *
 * @param genreIds takes list of genre Ids
 * @return list of String Genres
 */
public ArrayList<String> getGenres(List<Integer> genreIds){
    ArrayList<String> genres = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int genreId :genreIds) {
        switch (genreId) {
            case 28:
                genres.add("Action");
                break;
            case 12:
                genres.add("Adventure");
                break;
            case 16:
                genres.add("Animation");
                break;
            case 35:
                genres.add("Comedy");
                break;
            case 80:
                genres.add("Crime");
                break;
            case 99:
                genres.add("Documentary");
                break;
            case 18:
                genres.add("Drama");
                break;
            case 10751:
                genres.add("Family");
                break;
            case 14:
                genres.add("Fantasy");
                break;
            case 10796:
                genres.add("Foreign");
                break;
            case 36:
                genres.add("History");
                break;
            case 27:
                genres.add("Horror");
                break;
            case 10402:
                genres.add("Music");
                break;
            case 9648:
                genres.add("Mystery");
                break;
            case 10747:
                genres.add("Animation");
                break;
            case 878:
                genres.add("Science Fiction");
                break;
            case 10770:
                genres.add("TV Movie");
                break;
            case 53:
                genres.add("Thriller");
                break;
            case 10752:
                genres.add("War");
                break;
            case 37:
                genres.add("Western");
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return genres;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(adult ? 1 : 0);
    dest.writeString(backdropPath);
    dest.writeList(genreIds);
    dest.writeInt(id);
    dest.writeString(originalLanguage);
    dest.writeString(originalTitle);
    dest.writeString(overview);
    dest.writeString(releaseDate);
    dest.writeString(posterPath);
    dest.writeDouble(popularity);
    dest.writeString(title);
    dest.writeInt(video ? 1 : 0);
    dest.writeDouble(voteAverage);
    dest.writeInt(voteCount);
}


public static final Parcelable.Creator<Movie> CREATOR = new Parcelable.ClassLoaderCreator<Movie>() {

    @Override
    public Movie createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Movie(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Movie[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Movie[size];
    }

    @Override
    public Movie createFromParcel(Parcel source, ClassLoader loader) {
        return null;
    }
};
}
```

I am populating a `RecyclerView` of these objects. When I click on a RecyclerView item I want to pass that object via an intent to another activity.  However I keep getting a null pointer.

Here is my `onClick` where I add the parcelable to the intent

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Log.i("POSITION: ", String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()));
    Movie movie = mMovieList.get(getAdapterPosition());
    Intent detail = new Intent(mContext, MovieDetailActivity.class);
    //Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    //bundle.putParcelable("movie_object", movie);
    detail.putExtra("movie_object", movie);
    // detail.putExtras(bundle);
    mContext.startActivity(detail);
}
```

The commented lines are my attempts.

Here in the MovieDetailActivity is where I attempt to access the object:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Movie movie = i.getParcelableExtra("movie_object");  <--Null
```

I had implemented serializable and that was working fine, however, I now want to use the onSavedInstanceState method which requires parcelable.

I don't know what is wrong. Can anyone see the error?

Comment: why you have added @JsonProperty("adult")

Comment: @user3676184 I don't follow?  It's an object variable I require, so I'm adding it...Do you think it might be causing a problem?

Comment: I think so but I don't know exactly

Comment: it's an object variable of type boolean..Could you expand on how this might be causing issues?

Comment: Has anyone any ideas on this?  Very frustrating

Comment: have you used serializable..... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android

Comment: @user3676184 Yep, I mentioned that in the question, however, now I want to use the onSavedInstanceState method which required a parcelable array

Answer (score 0):

Try this : first activity pass mMovieList directly via intent:

```
Intent detail = new Intent(mContext, MovieDetailActivity.class);  
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("movie_object", mMovieList);
mContext.startActivity(detail);
```

And in second activity get movie list

```
List<Movie> mMovieList = new ArrayList<Movie>;
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
mMovieList = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("movie_object");
```

From list get your Movie object

Or else try this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/10114932/5202007

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your model or mMovieList here

```
Intent detail = new Intent(mContext, MovieDetailActivity.class);  
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("movie_object", mMovieList);
startActivity(detail);
```

And on another activity you can get it like this

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<mMovieList> mList=bundle.getParcelableArrayList("movie_object");
```