# Display data related in view (Activity) on click

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, button

I am getting my Json Object / Array from my Api and print it into my view,
foreach array I print the id the name in my MainActivity.

Foreach array data I create a button.
I want to move to another Activity and show the related data of the current array.

My view looks something like this:

```
________________________
id     name      button      <- if one clicks on the button another activity shall show the description of it
________________________
```

My big issue is how to show the related data in another activity.

My MainActivity looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    private final static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://192.168.178.58:8888/test";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        contactList = new ArrayList<>();

        new GetContacts().execute();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        String name = c.getString("name");
                        String description = c.getString("description");

                        // tmp hash map for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        data.put("id", id);
                        data.put("name", name);
                        data.put("description", description);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(data);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * In onPostExecute() method the progress dialog is dismissed and the array list data is displayed in list view using an adapter.
         * @param result
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[]{"name", "description"},
                    new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.description});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

}
```

Edit:

this is how I made an intent:

```
public void openDetails() { // button onclick name
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("key", value);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are the buttons that you are clicking? How are you starting the next activity?

Comment: I added the button in my xml I used an intent to go to the other activity, that worked but I could not get the related data

Comment: I don't see any methods here that are calling `startActivity`

Comment: ah sorry I removed them, it is a basic intent would you like that I add it?

Comment: Please. It would make it more clear what you've attempted.

Comment: @cricket_007 ok I added it

Answer (score 1):

In general you can use a singleton to share non primitive data between activities.

something like this,

```
public class MyData {
  private Object data;
  public Object getData() {
   return data;
  }
  public void setData(Object data) {
   this.data = data;
  }

  private static final MyData myData = new MyData();
  public static MyData getInstance() {
   return myData;
  }
}
```

then in the first activity:

```
MyData.getInstance().setData(objToShare);
```

and in the second:

```
objShared = MyData.getInstance().getData();
//do something
```

Comment: I do not quiet get how I should use this in my case

Comment: From what i have understood you want to share data between the main activity and a second one. when you receive the response from the api you can put the data retrieved in a singleton and follow the example i provided above.

Comment: In some cases I just use the `Application` class (assuming you override it) to store such things.

Comment: Data doesn't need stored app-wide. The question was just how to get an adapter item displayed in another Activity

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation doesn't know which button was clicked. All buttons are going to have the same click event.

Solution - don't put buttons on your ListView. Just handle a click on the "row".

To start this off, you'll want to replace your list of `HashMap<String, String>` in favor of a custom POJO class.

See - [Parcelable objects](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-Parcelable)

```
public class Contact implements Parcelable {
    private String id, name, description;

    // TODO: Getters & setters
    // TODO: Actually implement Parcelable
}
```

Then, update your adapter. Instead of a `SimpleAdapter`.

See - [Custom Adapter](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#using-a-custom-arrayadapter)

```
private ContactAdapter adapter; // Top of class
...
// onCreate
    contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new ContactAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter); // Set this here, not in the AsyncTask
...
// doInBackground
    contactList.add(someContact);
    // adapter.add(someContact); // Can also do this
// onPostExecute
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Refresh the adapter, don't lv.setAdapter again.
```

And your AsyncTask

```
    // tmp object for single contact
    Contact c = new Contact();

    // adding each child node to object
    c.setID(id);
    c.setName(name);
    c.setDescription(description);

    // adding contact to contact list
    contactList.add(c);
```

[Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) would help with this if you didn't want to do it manually. 
Retrofit could replace your whole AsyncTask, but I'll leave that up to you to research.

---

Now, back to the "click event".
Since this `Contact` object is `Parcelable`, you pass it through an Intent just like anything else.

```
// onCreate
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    // This is a click per-row
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {    
            Contact clicked = adapter.getItem(position);
            displayContact(clicked);  
        }
    });
```

I like defining separate methods to make the code clearer.

```
private void displayContact(Contact c) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("contact", c);  // The piece you're looking for
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

To get it from intent in another activity:

```
Contact c = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("contact");
```

Refer - [Android: How to pass Parcelable object to intent and use getParcelable method of bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107442/android-how-to-pass-parcelable-object-to-intent-and-use-getparcelable-method-of)

Comment: Thank you I will try this out and give you a reply

Comment: How excatly do I use Parcelable Objects I am struggling there right now

Comment: Did you read the links I provided? Which part are you stuck with?

Comment: I will look into the tutorial again I think I missed something

Comment: Alright. The most important pieces are that you'd have three `writeString` and `readString` method calls to the Parcel. The order there is important. Then, you need the `CREATOR` constant.

Comment: @utdev Or, you could [just use the plugin](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-Parcelable#creating-a-parcelable-the-easier-but-still-manual-way-using-intellij-or-android-studio)