# Passing object to CursorAdapter getting null

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-cursoradapter

I am getting a callback in my main activity that is passing an object of values from a ListView click. If I throw a toast the toast is displaying the key, value pairs. I want to take that and add it to the TopListCursorAdapter to populate a new row. I am getting null on the topAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Not sure how to add mEmployee to the adapter, I have tried to

```
@Override
public void onBottomListClick(Employee e) {
    mEmployee.add(e);
    dbHandler.addEmployee(e);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
    final Cursor clickedEmployee = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + "employees" + " WHERE " +
            "Employee_number" + "=" + e.getEmployee_number(), null);
    // change the adapter's Cursor
    topAdapter.changeCursor(clickedEmployee);
}
```

But I do not want to pass a cursor and the TopListCursorAdapter wants one. I just want to add mEmployee to the existing List in TopListCursorAdapter.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements BottomListViewAdapter.BottomListClickListener {
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    EmployeeDBHandler dbHandler;
    private TopListCursorAdapter topAdapter;
    private BottomListViewAdapter bottomAdapter;
    private ArrayList mEmployee;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        dbHandler = new EmployeeDBHandler(getApplicationContext());
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        getXMLData();

        //GUI for seeing android SQLite Database in Chrome Dev Tools
        Stetho.InitializerBuilder inBuilder = Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this);
        inBuilder.enableWebKitInspector(Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(this));
        Stetho.Initializer in = inBuilder.build();
        Stetho.initialize(in);
    }

    public void getXMLData() {
        OkHttpClient client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(getString(R.string.API_FULL_URL))
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                final String responseData = response.body().string();
                final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseData.getBytes());
                final XMLPullParserHandler parserHandler = new XMLPullParserHandler();
                final ArrayList<Employee> employees = (ArrayList<Employee>) parserHandler.parse(stream);

                for (Employee e : employees) {
                    dbHandler.addEmployee(e);
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        displayTopList();
                        displayBottomList();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public void displayTopList() {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.topFragment, new TopFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    public void displayBottomList() {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.bottomFragment, new BottomFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

 @Override
    public void onBottomListClick(Employee e) {
        mEmployee.add(e);
        dbHandler.addEmployee(e);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        final Cursor clickedEmployee = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + "employees" + " WHERE " +
                "Employee_number" + "=" + e.getEmployee_number(), null);
        // change the adapter's Cursor
        topAdapter.changeCursor(clickedEmployee);
    }
```

}

TopListCursorAdapter

```
public class TopListCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private EmployeeDBHandler dbHandler;
    private Activity activityRef;

    public TopListCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
        activityRef = (Activity) context;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.contact_cardview_layout, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        dbHandler = new EmployeeDBHandler(context);
        ViewHolder holder;
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvFirstName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personFirstName);
        holder.tvLastName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personLastName);
        holder.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personTitle);
        holder.mPeepPic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
        holder.mDetailsButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fullDetailButton);
        holder.mCardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.home_screen_cardView);

        String mFirstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("First_name"));
        String mLastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Last_name"));
        String mPayrollTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Payroll_title"));
        String mThumbnail = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ThumbnailData"));

        holder.tvFirstName.setText(mFirstName);
        holder.tvLastName.setText(mLastName);
        holder.tvTitle.setText(mPayrollTitle);

        if (mThumbnail != null) {
            byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(mThumbnail.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap parsedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
            holder.mPeepPic.setImageBitmap(parsedImage);
        } else {
            holder.mPeepPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_place_holder_adapter);
        }

        activityRef.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            }
        });


        final int position = cursor.getPosition();
        holder.mDetailsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                String mEmployeeNumber = cursor.getString(1);
                String mEmail = cursor.getString(8);
                String mFirstName = cursor.getString(2);
                String mLastName = cursor.getString(3);
                String mPhoneMobile = cursor.getString(4);
                String mPhoneOffice = cursor.getString(5);
                String mCostCenter = cursor.getString(10);
                String mHasDirectReports = cursor.getString(7);
                String mTitle = cursor.getString(6);
                String mPic = cursor.getString(9);
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, EmployeeFullInfo.class);
                mIntent.putExtra("Employee_number", mEmployeeNumber);
                mIntent.putExtra("Email", mEmail);
                mIntent.putExtra("First_name", mFirstName);
                mIntent.putExtra("Last_name", mLastName);
                mIntent.putExtra("Phone_mobile", mPhoneMobile);
                mIntent.putExtra("Phone_office", mPhoneOffice);
                mIntent.putExtra("Cost_center_id", mCostCenter);
                mIntent.putExtra("Has_direct_reports", mHasDirectReports);
                mIntent.putExtra("Payroll_title", mTitle);
                mIntent.putExtra("ThumbnailData", mPic);
                mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                v.getContext().startActivity(mIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvFirstName;
        TextView tvLastName;
        TextView tvTitle;
        ImageView mPeepPic;
        ImageButton mDetailsButton;
        CardView mCardView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not want to pass a cursor and the TopListCursorAdapter wants one

Sure. You have a `DBHandler` which can give you a `Cursor`.

```
dbHandler = new EmployeeDBHandler(getApplicationContext());
```

And you have an `addEmployee` method.

```
dbHandler.addEmployee(e);
```

So the question is - how did you create the `TopListCursorAdapter` without already having a `Cursor` since it is required??

---

Anyways, you should not stick a `EmployeeDBHandler` in the adapter.
It only wants a `Cursor`. Plus, you never seem to use that class in there.

```
public class TopListCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    // private EmployeeDBHandler dbHandler; // ** Not needed
    private Context mContext; // Don't need an Activity

    public TopListCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
        mContext = context; // Just a Context, no Activity
    }
```

And you should never need to create a `new TopListAdapter` after the first creation of one, you can call `changeCursor` directly on the existing adapter.

```
@Override
public void onBottomListClick(Employee e) {
    mEmployee.add(e);
    dbHandler.addEmployee(e);

    // topAdapter = new TopListCursorAdapter(); // ** Nope
    Cursor newCursor = dbHandler.getEmployees(); // TODO: Implement this
    topAdapter.changeCursor(newCursor); // Updates the UI itself

    Intent employeeDetail = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EmployeeFullInfo.class);
    employeeDetail.putExtra("Employee_number", e.getNumber());
    ... 
    startActivity(employeeDetail);
}
```

Note: If you [use `Parcelable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107442/android-how-to-pass-parcelable-object-to-intent-and-use-getparcelable-method-of) `Employee` objects, you do not need a bunch `putExtra` and `getExtra` methods on the Intents.

---

Additionally, you can store an Employee object as part of the ViewHolder for simpler data management. That way, you only need to extract data from the `Cursor` into an `Employee`, then the ViewHolder can maintain that since you are duplicating the effort within `onClick` to get the `Cursor` data.

```
public static class ViewHolder {
    Employee employee; // See here
    TextView tvFirstName;
    TextView tvLastName;
    TextView tvTitle;
    ImageView mPeepPic;
    ImageButton mDetailsButton;
    CardView mCardView;
}
```

Comment: I have a cursor being passed to the adapter from a Fragment that has a rawQuery getting a row to add to the TopListView. This is adding an employee to the existing database. The employee already exists in the DB.

Comment: I was just trying to point out that `new TopListCursorAdapter();` is not what you want. You should instead call `changeCursor`, and however you get that Cursor needs to be queried from the database.

Comment: Trying to figure out how to getEmployees as I have getEmployee to accept an employeeNumber and have getAllEmployees that takes an ArrayList. I can just pass the getEmployee the employeeNumber from the Employee e to add just the row to the toplist?

Comment: Make a new method then and `return getReadableDatabase().query(TABLE_NAME, null, null ,null, null, null, null, null)`

Comment: Wouldn't that just add the entire table to the TopList? I just want the 1 row the user clicked in BottomList to be added to TopList.

Comment: I updated my onBottomListClick like you suggested, added a raqQuery and tried to change the Cursor but still get null on topAdapter.

Comment: @AdamGardner Did you find your solution?

Comment: For the null issue yes, just not for the final solution of adding the click event from bottom list and adding that to the listview in topList.