# How to populate values to variables of a parcelable class whose object we are sending from one activity to the other

Tags: android, parcelable

Stack trace:

```
11-16 20:39:42.374 30640-30703/? E/LocalFingerprints: cannot compute fingerprint for: content://media/external/images/media/41373
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
      at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:146)
      at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:682)
      at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1063)
      at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:904)
      at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:629)
      at cak.a(PG:159)
      at bzj.a(PG:123)
      at com.google.android.apps.plus.service.FingerprintScannerIntentService.onHandleIntent(PG:79)
      at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
      at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

This is the FirstActivity:

```
  void handleBlogEditClick(){
       if (BlogDetailActivity.this!= null) {
            BlogDetailVO blogDetailVO=new BlogDetailVO(getArgs().getmId(),getArgs().getmName().toString(),getArgs().getmDescription().toString());
            blogDetailVO.mCoverPic.setmImageUrl(getArgs().getmImageUrl());
            Intent intent = new Intent(BlogDetailActivity.this, EditBlogActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            intent.putExtra("blogDetailVO",blogDetailVO);
            startActivity(intent);
       }
    }
```

Second activity:

```
mState = new EditBlogState();
Intent intent = getIntent();
BlogDetailVO blogDetailVO =(BlogDetailVO) intent.getParcelableExtra("blogDetailVO");
mState.mCoverPhotoStory.setmName(blogDetailVO.getmName());
mView.updateBlogTitle(mState.mCoverPhotoStory.getmName());
```

Other things in the first and second activity code is irrelevant to this so i shared this much

```
public class BlogDetailVO extends BlogFeedVO implements Parcelable{

    PhotoStoryVO mCoverPic;
    List<PhotoStoryVO> mPhotoStories;
    LocationVO mLocationVO;

    public BlogDetailVO(String mId, String mName, String mDescription) {
        super(mId, mName, mDescription);
    }

    protected BlogDetailVO(Parcel in) {
        super(in);

        mCoverPic = in.readParcelable(PhotoStoryVO.class.getClassLoader());
        mPhotoStories = in.createTypedArrayList(PhotoStoryVO.CREATOR);
        mLocationVO = in.readParcelable(LocationVO.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);

        dest.writeParcelable(mCoverPic, flags);
        dest.writeTypedList(mPhotoStories);
        dest.writeParcelable(mLocationVO, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return hashCode();
    }

    public static final Creator<BlogDetailVO> CREATOR = new Creator<BlogDetailVO>() {
        @Override
        public BlogDetailVO createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new BlogDetailVO(in);
        }

        @Override
        public BlogDetailVO[] newArray(int size) {
            return new BlogDetailVO[size];
        }
    };

    public PhotoStoryVO getmCoverPic() {
        return mCoverPic;
    }

    public void setmCoverPic(PhotoStoryVO mCoverPic) {
        this.mCoverPic = mCoverPic;
    }


    public List<PhotoStoryVO> getmPhotoStories() {
        return mPhotoStories;
    }

    public void setmPhotoStories(List<PhotoStoryVO> mPhotoStories) {
        this.mPhotoStories = mPhotoStories;
    }

    public LocationVO getmLocationVO() {
        return mLocationVO;
    }

    public void setmLocationVO(LocationVO mLocationVO) {
        this.mLocationVO = mLocationVO;
    }
}
```

I am new to android. so sorry if the question is silly. But i am really stuck and need help. i am sending BlogDetailVO class object to another activity. The second line is showing null. so can't i populate value in this way? Eventually it crashes.

```
BlogDetailVO blogDetailVO=new BlogDetailVO(getArgs().getmId(),getArgs().getmName().toString(),getArgs().getmDescription().toString());
blogDetailVO.mCoverPic.setmImageUrl(getArgs().getmImageUrl()); //this gives the error!!
Intent intent = new Intent(BlogDetailActivity.this, EditBlogActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
intent.putExtra("blogDetailVO",blogDetailVO);  startActivity(intent);
```

So how to populate values to BlogDtailVO class so to send it to the other activity?
In the receiving activity I am receiving it this way:

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 BlogDetailVO blogDetailVO =(BlogDetailVO) intent.getParcelableExtra("blogDetailVO");
```

Comment: Are you  accessing or sending the values from  the fragment or Activity?

Comment: I am trying to send the values from one activity to the other

Comment: Ok Post Complete Activity Code of these two activity . Let me give you a solutioin.

Comment: Just wanted to know how can i populate values to variables of BlogDetailVO class so as to send it to the other activity

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107442/android-how-to-pass-parcelable-object-to-intent-and-use-getparcelable-method-of)

Comment: if you want to have a crash solved please provide the stack trace

Comment: BlogDetailVO blogDetailVO=new BlogDetailVO(getArgs().getmId(),getArgs().getmName().toString(),getArgs().getmDescription().toString());

Confused in that line , Where are you getting getArgs() values .

Comment: I have given the trace @PeppermintPaddy

Comment: From here   BlogFeedVO getArgs() {
        return getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(Constants.DATA);
    }

Comment: I just wanted to know how can i populate values in variables of BlogDetailVO class using the blogDetailVO object and send the same to the other activity