# How to put in one activity in one javafile when you call a function instead of many, Android

Tags: java, android

So I have this fab menu and each button have different activity what I want is to put the functions into one java file instead of creating a lot of java file to call different functions in the button

Here's the one of the java file - `SVAuditorium.class`.

```
public class SVAuditorium extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final LatLng Auditorium = new LatLng(10.294335, 123.880809);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.street_view);

        SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment streetViewPanoramaFragment =
                (SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment)
                        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.streetviewpanorama);
        streetViewPanoramaFragment.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(
                new OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama panorama) {
                        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                            panorama.setPosition(Auditorium);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

This is what I did to call the activities from the `SVAuditorium` and the rest.

```
case R.id.fab_auditorium:
    startActivity(new Intent(this, SVSAuditorium.class));
    break;
case R.id.fab_library:
    startActivity(new Intent(this, SVLibrary.class));
    break;
case R.id.fab_main:
    startActivity(new Intent(this, SVMainBuilding.class));
    break;
```

Comment: which functions you want in one java file?

Comment: SVAuditorium because I have like 10 SVnamed java how to put all of this like in one java file @ZaidMirza

Comment: your SVNamed classes representing  Activities,not functions.

Comment: `private static final LatLng Auditorium = new LatLng(10.294335, 123.880809);` I only need to change the latitute and longitude in each java file so is it ok to create this many java?? @ZaidMirza

Comment: I think this is Ok . Its all depends on what what exactly the function does . For instance a function `dpToPX()` convert the value to pixel and uses throughout the application so in this case its better to put this function in a Utility class as `dpToPx(Context context)`. Get the point ?

Comment: Elaborate pls @ADM

Comment: @Batmon are you saying all SVnamed files have same functionality but only LatLng is different?

Comment: Yes the Latlng is only different @ZaidMirza

Comment: I guess you have created one class per StreetView

Answer (score 1):

As you have stated that you only have changes in lat-long in each of your `Activity`, I would suggest keeping a single activity like you want and pass the lat-long through intent. Here's a sample code showing how you can achieve the behaviour.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SVActivity.class);
Bundle longLat = new Bundle();
longLat.putDouble("LONGITUDE", longitude);
longLat.putDouble("LATITUDE", latitude);
intent.putExtras(longLat);
startActivity(intent);
```

Get the latitude and longitude in your `SVActivity` like this.

```
Bundle longLat = getIntent().getExtras();
double longitude = longLat.getDouble("LONGITUDE");
double latitude = longLat.getDouble("LATITUDE");
```

Initialize your views based on the value found in your `SVActivity`.

Answer (score 1):

> the Latlng is only different

Since `LatLng implements Parcelable`

You need only need **one** Java file and you can pass the LatLng through an Intent using `Intent.putExtra("latlng", latlng)`, where you define that variable per clicked item

See answer - [Android: How to pass Parcelable object to intent and use getParcelable method of bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107442/android-how-to-pass-parcelable-object-to-intent-and-use-getparcelable-method-of)

Then in that one Activity's onCreate method, you can `LatLng latlng = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("latlng")`