# Handling a large number of items in a listview

Tags: android, listview

I am creating a directory of schools in android application and want to open their details on new page by clicking on it from list view. how should i handle it?

Comment: RecycleView is best for large list data.

Comment: RecyclerView with load more option is the best way to handle big set of data. Find a link for example https://github.com/Pyush/Android-RecyclerView-Loadmore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use a RecyclerView.
You can find a simple example [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview).

Answer (score 1):

make Pojo of the student info and pass it to the next activity using parcelable object

Comment: Would you please elaborate this? I didn't get it

Comment: You have class of the student information implement the parcelable and pass it to the next activity intent.putparcelableextra("KEY","OBJECT"); try this link you will get the idea   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107442/android-how-to-pass-parcelable-object-to-intent-and-use-getparcelable-method-of