# How to pass data between activity using parcelable in android studio

Tags: java, android, parcelable

i have a recyclerview shows the list of movie,
i want when the item movie clicked can pass data to detail using parcelable

this my viewHolderAdapter

```
public class MovieVHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView mTxtTitleMovie, mTxtDescriptionMovie, mTxtDateMovie;
        ImageView mImgPosterMovie;

        public MovieVHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTxtTitleMovie = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title_movie);
            mTxtDescriptionMovie = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_desc_movie);
            mTxtDateMovie = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_date_movie);
            mImgPosterMovie = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_movie);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(i);
                }
            });

        }

        public void bind(ListMovieEntity listMovieEntity) {
            mTxtTitleMovie.setText(listMovieEntity.getMovieTittle());
            mTxtDescriptionMovie.setText(listMovieEntity.getMovieDescription());
            mTxtDateMovie.setText(listMovieEntity.getMovieDate());
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/"+listMovieEntity.getMoviePosterPath())
                    .into(mImgPosterMovie);
        }
    }
```

and I've added parcelable in model class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: How to pass Parcelable object to intent and use getParcelable method of bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107442/android-how-to-pass-parcelable-object-to-intent-and-use-getparcelable-method-of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change itemviewclick like this

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
    //addthis       i.putExtra(DetailActivity.MOVIE, entListMovie.get(getPosition()));
                    context.startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```

and in the detail make like this

add this

```
public static final String MOVIE = "movie";
```

in method onCreate() add this

```
YourList yourList = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(MOVIE);
```

after that, just set the data

```
textview.setText(yourList.getBlaBla());
```

Comment: @AlFajri you also need to override `writeToParcel` method in your model

Comment: @MohitAjwani ya i've added that using generator parcelable

Answer (score 0):

Intent supports three ways to pass data:

**Direct: put our data into intents directly**

**Bundle: create a bundle and set the data here**

**Parcelable: It is a way of “serializing” our object.**

**Passing data: Direct**

```
 Intent i = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
i.putExtra("title", mTxtTitleMovie.getText().toString();
i.putExtra("surname", edtSurname.getText().toString();
i.putExtra("email", edtEmail.getText().toString();
context.startActivity(i);
```

**Bundle**

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("name", edtName.getText().toString());
b.putString("surname", edtSurname.getText().toString());
b.putString("email", edtEmail.getText().toString());
i.putExtra("personBdl", b);

context.startActivity(i);
```

**Passing data: Parcelable**

Let’s suppose we have a class called Person that contains three attributes:name, surname and email.

Now if we want to pass this class it must **implement** the **Parcelable** interface like that

```
public class Person implements Parcelable {
private String name;
private String surname;
private String email;
// Get and Set methods

@Override
public int describeContents() {
return hashCode();
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
dest.writeString(name);
dest.writeString(surname);
dest.writeString(email);
}

// We reconstruct the object reading from the Parcel data
public Person(Parcel p) {
name = p.readString();
surname = p.readString();
email = p.readString();
}

public Person() {}

// We need to add a Creator
public static final Parcelable.Creator&lt;person&gt; CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator&lt;person&gt;() {

@Override
public Person createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
return new Person(parcel);
}

@Override
public Person[] newArray(int size) {
return new Person[size];
}
};
```

Now we simply pass data like that:

```
Intent i = new Intent(EditActivity.this, ViewActivity.class);
Person p = new Person();
p.setName(edtName.getText().toString());
p.setSurname(edtSurname.getText().toString());
p.setEmail(edtEmail.getText().toString());
i.putExtra("myPers", p);
startActivity(i);
```

As you notice we simply put our object Person into the Intent. When we receive the data we have:

```
Bundle b = i.getExtras();
Person p = (Person) b.getParcelable("myPers");
String name = p.getName();
String surname = p.getSurname();
String email = p.getEmail();
```